# R not finding .txt file to read in using read.table

Tags: r, read.table

I have a tab separated .txt file that I'm trying to read into my project.  It consists of 4 'columns', though I only need the last 2.  I have tried several commands, getting several errors.

```
movieTimes = read.table("absolute path", header=F, sep='\t')
```

error:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
>   = dec,  :    line 304 did not have 4 elements

My program is only 100 lines...

I also tried:

```
movieTimes = read.table("movies.txt", header=F, sep='\t')
```

error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
>   'movies.txt': No such file or directory

I know that it's in the same folder as my program...

I also tried:

```
movieTimes = read.table("MOVIES.TXT", header=F, sep='\t')
```

and got the same error as above.  How should I fix this?  I also used the <- as well for all of these cases

Comment: R can't see your file, so there must be an error in the path or filename or both. Try navigating to the directory where your data is using `setwd('/that/directory')` and type `dir()` to see what is displayed. If you don't see your file name there, then R can't see it either. Also, take advantage of tab-completion when you're filling in filenames... this is a good way to make sure R can see the file you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are in the same folder with your R script and you are using RStudio then you can set your working directory automatically using `rstudioapi` package. Doing it this way will eliminate the need for a hard-coded working directory

```
install.packages("rstudioapi", dependencies = TRUE)
library(rstudioapi)
currentDir <- dirname(getActiveDocumentContext()$path)
currentDir
setwd(currentDir)
```

Then list all the files with `.txt` extension to see what the correct syntax of `movies.txt` is

```
fileList <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = FALSE,
                       pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE))
fileList
```

Comment: According to R Studio, there is no package called rstudioapi when I typed library(rstudioapi)

Comment: You have to install it. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstudioapi/index.html